# telebot работа с voice. convert ogg to wav

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, wav, ogg

качаю файл и сохраняю его в папке с программой с помощью скрипта

```
file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
file = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}'.format(token, file_info.file_path))

f=open('voice.ogg','wb')
f.write(file.content)
f.close()
text= audio_to_txt('voice.ogg')
```

после чего пытаюсь конвертировать полученный файл в формат wav

```
import soundfile as sf   #   pip install pysoundfile

data, samplerate = sf.read('voice.ogg')
sf.write('new_file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

В результате получаю ошибку

Error opening 'voice.ogg': File contains data in an unimplemented format

С помощью сторонних программ запись открывается без проблем, причем, если c помощью сторонней программы перевести в wav, а потом обратно в ogg полученный в результате файл без проблем конвертируется с помощью указанного кода.

как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile/issues/251 может поможет, так же вы можете воспользоваться `ffmpeg -i in.ogg -c:a pcm_f32le out.wav` через `subprocess` например